# Combining Sidr menu with animated hamburger button

Tags: jquery, menu, icons, animated, sidr

**My test page**
https://osticketawesome.com/support/awesome/inc/test.html

I'm trying to combine a hamburger menu with the Sidr jQuery plugin for creating side menus.

It works perfectly in Chrome, FF, IE and Edge but in the **mobile browsers** I've tested (Android/Chrome and iPhone/Safari) **the menu toggles but the button only animates if I tap on the outside edge of the button.**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="right-menu" href="#right-menu">
        <button href="#right-menu" class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx">
            <span>toggle menu</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>  

$(document).ready(function() {
    var toggles = document.querySelectorAll(".c-hamburger");
    for (var i = toggles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var toggle = toggles[i];
      toggleHandler(toggle);
    };
    function toggleHandler(toggle) {
      toggle.addEventListener( "click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        (this.classList.contains("is-active") === true) ?
            this.classList.remove("is-active") : 
            this.classList.add("is-active");
      });
    }
   $('.c-hamburger').sidr({
        name: 'right_menu',
        side: 'right',
        body: 'container'
    }); 
})();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this. In case it helps anyone later on, I simply doubled-up on the following function:

```
function toggleHandler(toggle) {
  toggle.addEventListener( "click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    (this.classList.contains("is-active") === true) ? this.classList.remove("is-active") : this.classList.add("is-active");
  });
  toggle.addEventListener( "touchstart", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    (this.classList.contains("is-active") === true) ? this.classList.remove("is-active") : this.classList.add("is-active");
  });     
}
```